# iPhone SDK/General Xcode question

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uilabel, ibaction, iboutlet

In the iPhone SDK, in my .n, I can say:

```
-(IBOutlet) UITextField *MyNameIs;
-(IBOutlet) UILabel *DisplayMyNameIsHere;

}

-(IBAction)PressButtonToDisplayYourName;
```

Then in my .m, I'll do:

```
-(IBAction)PressButtonToDisplayYourName {
     DisplayMyNameIsHere = MyNameIs.text;
}
```

But now how would I translate that to making a Mac application. If I wanted to display someones name from a textfield in a label? I have been trying to figure this out, but the ".text" extension only works in the iPhone SDK, not the Mac SDK. Someone please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to a Cocoa application, you could do the following in your .h file:

`IBOutlet NSTextField *myLabel;`

`IBOutlet NSTextField *myTextField;`

`-(IBAction)displayName:(id)sender;`

And then you could implement it in the .m file:

***EDITED FOR COCOA:***

`-(IBAction)displayName:(id)sender{
[myLabel setStringValue:[myTextField stringValue]];
}`

Comment: It didn't work..It gave me an error.

"'NSTextField' may not respond to '-text'"

Comment: I'm trying to do this on a Mac application.....I already know how to do it in the iPhone SDK.

Comment: Sorry- I gave you the wrong property- I think it's "stringValue".

So it should be, `[myLabel setText:[myTextField stringValue]];`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I managed to figure it out after the last response. It wasn't [myLabel setText:[myTextField stringValue]];, it was [myLabel setStringValue:[myTextField stringValue]]; I typed set then hit the esc key and looked through and I found setStringValue. So it worked. Thanks for the help guys!!! Its a reference application. =)

Comment: There we go! (That was a little confusion between Cocoa's and iOs's methods).

Yeah, I find it helpful to hit the escape key once in a while to fine out what method I should use.